# Read Octopus variables

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy, octopus

I am new to octopus and have a bunch of steps. For each steps we have "Machine Roles".

As part of the steps I have a script tasks/step and I wish to access the roles assigned to this step in the (powershell) script. How can I achieve this.

I tried a few things, i.e. Octopus.Machine.Roles, Octopus.Tentacle.CurrentDeployment.TargetedRoles in the (powershell) script. But does not see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in [this example](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/06/packaging-visual-studio-database-project-with-octopack/), if you have a variable in Octopus, you can access it using the variable name, prefixed with a $ in PowerShell, so for a variable `TestUrl` use:

```
$TestUrl
```

For Octopus Parameters, you use the following:

```
$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Machine.Roles']
```

This should give you access to all the [system variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables).

Comment: any idea how to get $TestUrl in bash? without $(get_octopusvariable ' $TestUrl')?